# Xcode 8, Xcode 9 fatal error: too many errors emitted

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcode9

My project is properly worked in xcode 8. So I delete the xcode 8 and I install the xcode 9. Then I run the application I faced following error

xcode 9

> fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] 20
>   errors generated. While building module 'UIKit' imported from

........

> could not build module foundation "#import `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`"
>
> could not build module foundation "#import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`"

So I clear the build, and drived data folder. Even I update the cocoapod also. But it is not working. After that I delete the xcode 9 and I install the xcode8 and xcode 9. Currently I have xcode 8 and xcode 9. Now my project is working both xcode 8 and xcode 9.

Anybody have any idea?

Note:

I checked with two different PCs. Both have the same issue.

Comment: So, it's working with Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 and you want to know why it works? I don't get it.

Comment: @dasdom. Yes. I want to know, If I use xcode 9 only, why it is not working?  I checked with two different PCs. Both have the same issue.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @dasdom i update the error.  could not build module foundation "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>"

could not build module foundation "#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>"